# Using .hasClass() in if condition is not works

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a div when user hover on it will insert a div `child` div. 
But the problem is on every hover it added the same div repeatably. so i tried the below script for check if `child` div availabe in `MotherDiv` do nothing. else add the `Child` div. These all are happen on hover. So, What is the wrong with the below code?

Am i missing something?

```
if ($('.MotherDiv').hasClass('Child'))
{
alert('alerady a div there!');//DO NOTHING
}
else 
 {        
 var Details= "<div class='MotherDiv'><table class='Special'><tr><td>Offers</td></tr><tr><td>CheckOut Now</td></tr></table></div>";
  $(Child).insertAfter($(this));//This is insert the child div on hover
}
```

Comment: Where is this 'Child' css class being added? Maybe you should check if it has any children rather than looking for a class?

Comment: Are you putting that code inside hover function?

Comment: Where are you using the `Details` variable? Maybe i'm not getting the question but it seems your problem description and your code are in contradiction. As per your description, `Motherdiv` should already be in the DOM and you just want to add the `Child` div dynamically, is that right?

Comment: yes if the `child` div is present we not need to add the `child` div if the `motherdiv` didn't have the child div we need to add it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this. Simply adds new Child class if the div doesn't have. If you need to add new child div inside mother div then you just have to customize the code a bit.

http://jsfiddle.net/ETuZB/3/

Answer (score 2):

Your JavaScript snipplet you shown above is invalid. You can not have line breaks in it like that.

You can add a `\` at the end of the line to denote that it is continued, but it is normally frowned upon as a bad practice.

```
if ($('.MotherDiv').hasClass('Child')) {
    alert('alerady a div there!');//DO NOTHING
} else {        
    var Details= "<div class='MotherDiv'>\
       <table class='Special'>\
       <tr><td>Offers</td></tr>\
       <tr><td>CheckOut Now</td></tr>\
       </table>\
       </div>";
    $(Child).insertAfter($(this));//This is insert the child div on hover
}
```

Note, there can not be any characters after the `\` or it will error out.

Comment: I think there's a lot more going on here than this. This should have been a comment, or at the very least you should've shown how to fix the problem. Anyway, you fix it by escaping the line with a `\\` to insinuate a carriage return. (I just realized I don't know how to escape in SO. Anyone?)

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: *Nevermind, that didn't work.* http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129704/how-do-you-type-a-single-backslash-in-a-comment

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be that you have a string that spans multiple lines.
JavaScript does not handle strings that way.  You need to either break the string into parts and concatenate them `"..." + "..."`, or use a line termination escape `\` to preserve the newline and following whitespace.

```
var Details= "<div class='MotherDiv'>
 <table class='Special'>
   <tr><td>Offers</td></tr>
   <tr><td>CheckOut Now</td></tr>
 </table>
 </div>";
```

To:

```
var Details = "<div class='MotherDiv'>"
            + "<table class='Special'>"
            + "<tr><td>Offers</td></tr>"
            + "<tr><td>CheckOut Now</td></tr>"
            + "</table>
            + "</div>";
```

Or:

```
var Details = "<div class='MotherDiv'>              \
                  <table class='Special'>           \
                     <tr><td>Offers</td></tr>       \
                     <tr><td>CheckOut Now</td></tr> \
                   </table>                         \
                </div>";
```

Comment: +1, not sure why you were down voted other than lacking a description of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is the HTML structure you want to generate:

```
<div class="Mother">
    Mother Div Content
    <div class="Child">
        Child Div to be generated dynamically
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery Script:

```
$(".Mother").hover(function(){
    var motherDiv = $(this);
    if(motherDiv.find(".Child").length == 0) {
        var childDiv = $("<div class='Child'>Child Div Content</div>");
        motherDiv.append(childDiv);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    var $motherDiv=$('.MotherDiv');
    $motherDiv.bind('mouseenter',
    function(){
        if($motherDiv.find('.ChildDiv').length==0){
            $('<div></div>',{class:'ChildDiv',text:'Child Data Text'}).appendTo($motherDiv);
        }
    });});
```

Answer (score -1):

Where is `.MotherDiv` being added to the document?  You don't seem to be inserting `$(Details)`.

Comment: Not a solution, but a comment. -1